# dropdownlistfor not displaying correct value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My query is getting all the correct values and the selectlist is populated, but my dropdownlist only shows the first value in the selectlist.  how can i get it to show the returned value of Captain?

Viewmodel:

```
public class EditTeamsView : BaseCommunityView
    {   
       ...
        public IList<Domain.Team> ExistingTeams { get; set; }            
     ...
        public EditTeamsView()
        {               
            ExistingTeams = new List<Domain.Team>();

        }

    }

 public class Team
    { 
        ...       
        public string Captain { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MemberSelectList { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@for (var c = 0; c < Model.ExistingTeams.Count; c++)
                    {
                      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExistingTeams[c].Captain, Model.ExistingTeams[c].MemberSelectList,
                                        new { @class = "form-control "})
}
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to use jQuery in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each option in the dropdown will need a value property and a display property so you may need to change up your Team class's MemberSelectList object to IEnumerable that contains value and text properties.

To set the default value of a drop down list based on a string value like what you have, new up a SelectList that requires an IEnumerable list of objects like what you have, a value property, a text property, and then the default value object.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ExistingTeams[c].Captain, 
    new SelectList(Model.MemberSelectList, "Value", "Text", Model.Captain)
)
```

Comment: this sounds like the problem as in my query, my list is created with a simpleselectlist.   MemberSelectList = team.Members.ToSimpleSelectList();  I will create it properly and report back

Comment: yes your solution works, thank you.  I also understand selectlists better now too. :)

Comment: would just like to add, that the code that worked in my case was like this:  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Captain, new SelectList(Model.ExistingTeams[c].MemberSelectList, "Value", "Text", Model.ExistingTeams[c].Captain),
                                        new { @class = "form-control "})